# How can I convert 2411 where 24 is the date and 11 is the month to a date format 2018-11-24 in SQL

Tags: sql-server

How can I convert 2411 where 24 is the date and 11 is the month, in the following date format: `2018-11-24` in SQL.

Comment: Didn't you say `11 is the month` ? and the date is `2018-10-24` ? Also where does 2018 comes from ? How do you know it is 2018 or any other year ? And `2411` is in string or numeric ?

Comment: my Bad.. i have edited my post now.. 2411 is string.
i want my final output to be yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: you should leave the formatting to the front end application where the date is display. Don't format it in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you want the date in current year and the input is an integer value

```
declare @intdate int

select @intdate = 2411

select dateadd(day, @intdate / 100 - 1, 
               dateadd(month, @intdate % 100 - 1, 
                       dateadd(year, year(getdate()) - 1900, 0)))
```

Comment: please mark the it as answered if it does resolved your issue